# Swift generics in lldb - error: unable to find any types that match the raw type for full type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, lldb

I have this bit of code:

```
class Talker:NSObject {
    func describe<T: Showable, U:Showable>(stuffs: [Blob<T, U>]) {
        let useless:Int = 71
        print("useless = \(useless)")
        for s in stuffs {
            print("s = \(s)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint inside the `for` loop. I am trying to display the value of `stuffs` in **lldb**. I get this:

```
(lldb) po stuffs
error: <EXPR>:2:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'stuffs'
stuffs
^~~~
(lldb) frame variable -L stuffs
0x00007fff5be1b9d8: ([Fork.Blob<T, Fork.Stem>]) stuffs = 1 value {
:   [0] = <Unable to determine byte size.>
}
```

So I tried this:

```
(lldb) register read pc
    rip = 0x000000010240209d  Fork`Fork.Talker.describe <A, B where A: Fork.Showable, B: Fork.Showable> (Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<A, B>>) -> () + 1741 at Blossom.swift:89
(lldb) image lookup -va 0x000000010240209d
      Address: Fork[0x000000010000709d] (Fork.__TEXT.__text + 25389)
      Summary: Fork`Fork.Talker.describe <A, B where A: Fork.Showable, B: Fork.Showable> (Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<A, B>>) -> () + 1741 at Blossom.swift:89
       Module: file = "/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fork-gdjlcshhkbqtnyajeeyaxbaeesyu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Fork.app/Fork", arch = "x86_64"
  CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "/Users/abc/Code/Fork/Fork/Blossom.swift", language = "swift"
     Function: id = {0x300001272}, name = "@convention(method) (Fork.Talker) -> <T : Showable, U : Showable> (Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<T, U>>) -> ()", range = [0x00000001024019d0-0x0000000102402413)
     FuncType: id = {0x300001272}, byte-size = 8, decl = Blossom.swift:85, compiler_type = "@convention(method) Fork.Talker -> <T : Showable, U : Showable> [Fork.Blob<T, U>] -> ()
"
       Blocks: id = {0x300001272}, range = [0x1024019d0-0x102402413)
               id = {0x3000012cd}, range = [0x1024019fc-0x102402413)
               id = {0x3000012ed}, range = [0x102401b8d-0x1024023d4)
    LineEntry: [0x000000010240209d-0x000000010240211c): /Users/abc/Code/Fork/Fork/Blossom.swift:89:19
       Symbol: id = {0x0000022c}, range = [0x00000001024019d0-0x0000000102402420), name="Fork.Talker.describe <A, B where A: Fork.Showable, B: Fork.Showable> (Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<A, B>>) -> ()", mangled="_TFC4Fork6Talker8describeu0_RxS_8Showable_S1_rfGSaGVS_4Blobxq___T_"
     Variable: id = {0x3000012fe}, name = "s", type = "Fork.Blob<T, U>", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-664), decl = Blossom.swift:88
     Variable: id = {0x3000012de}, name = "useless", type = "Swift.Int", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-96), decl = Blossom.swift:86
     Variable: id = {0x300001294}, name = "stuffs", type = "Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<T, U>>", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-80), decl = Blossom.swift:85
     Variable: id = {0x3000012a3}, name = "self", type = "Fork.Talker", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-88), decl = Blossom.swift:85
     Variable: id = {0x3000012b3}, name = "$swift.type.T", type = "Builtin.RawPointer", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-48), decl = 
     Variable: id = {0x3000012c0}, name = "$swift.type.U", type = "Builtin.RawPointer", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-56), decl = 
(lldb) memory read -t "Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<T, U>>" -a $fp-80
error: unable to find any types that match the raw type 'Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<T, U>>' for full type 'Swift.Array<Fork.Blob<T, U>>'
```

How can I inform **lldb** of the full type?

To check my syntax, I see I can display the value of `useless` accurately.

```
(lldb) memory read -t "Swift.Int" -a $fp-96
(Int) 0x7fff5d801390 = 71
```

**Note:** I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2.

### Update

Jim Ingham was correct. This was just a bug from Xcode 7 and Swift 2.2.

Using Xcode 8.2 I can `po stuffs` now and see debug output.

```
(lldb) po stuffs
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : Blob<Blossom, Stem>
    ▿ thing : <Fork.Blossom: 0x600000058210>
    ▿ otherThings : Optional<Array<Stem>>
      ▿ some : 2 elements
        ▿ 0 : <Fork.Stem: 0x60800005a880>
        ▿ 1 : <Fork.Stem: 0x60800005a2e0>
  ▿ 1 : Blob<Blossom, Stem>
    ▿ thing : <Fork.Blossom: 0x600000058240>
    ▿ otherThings : Optional<Array<Stem>>
      ▿ some : 2 elements
        ▿ 0 : <Fork.Stem: 0x60800005a880>
        ▿ 1 : <Fork.Stem: 0x60800005a2e0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to tell lldb the type.  OTOH, lldb has to be able to figure out what the fully resolved type of this argument is at runtime, and that can be tricky.

If this is Xcode 7 or Swift 2.x, you might try with Xcode 8/Swift 3.0.  lldb got a fair bit better at this task with some help from the Swift 3.0 compiler.  If it still doesn't work with Swift 3.0, please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Sure, I shouldn't have to, but what if I wanted to supply the type to `memory read` for `stuffs`, which is an array of structs parameter with generics? Is there a way I could do that to work around the potentially bug in Xcode 7.3.1?

Comment: You might be able to use the UnsafePointer(bitPattern:) initializer in the expression command to make a Swift object out of the address, and then use `as` to cast it to the type you know it actually is.

Comment: It was just an Xcode bug with generics all along. Thanks. Fixed in Xcode 8.2.